# Postgresql model array object with spring boot 2.0 not working

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-jdbc

```
public class Post {
    @Column(name="tags")
    private String[] tags;
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Post.Java

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>9.4-1206-jdbc42</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

POM.XML

```
@GetMapping("/posts")
    public List<Post> getAllPosts() {
        return postRepository.findAll();
    }
```

Controller

```
@Repository
public interface PostRepository extends JpaRepository<Post, Long> {

}
```

Repository

```
spring.datasource.url= jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/arya2?useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username=****
spring.datasource.password=***
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults = false
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect
```

Calling Rest Get Request, http://localhost:8081/posts
NOT SHOWING and this error

There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
could not deserialize; nested exception is org.hibernate.type.SerializationException: could not deserialize

and

java.sql.SQLFeatureNotSupportedException: Method org.postgresql.jdbc42.Jdbc42Connection.createClob() is not yet implemented.

Comment: So you're saving it as a `bytea` column by the looks of it. Or do you intend to use PostgreSQL arrays?

Comment: yes, i intend to use PostgreSQL arrays?

Comment: Then you can add this to your dependencies (minimum Hibernate 5.2 required) and not change your code at all https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.mopano/hibernate-array-contributor